# How to block uninstalling a module if some content refer to its configuration?

Tags: configuration

I have made a module that create a paragraph type, by adding yaml files in the config/install folder

Once installed, i have created some node contents containing nested paragraphs using the one provided by the module.

Those yaml files contains the module dependency, allowing to delete the configs when uninstalling the module.

```
dependencies:
  module:
    - my_module
```

When uninstalling the module , my node contents pages are not loadable, nor the edit page.

```
Call to a member function getEnabledBehaviorPlugins() on null in Drupal\paragraphs\ParagraphViewBuilder->buildMultiple() (line 37 of modules/contrib/paragraphs/src/ParagraphViewBuilder.php
```

How to ask to delete the associated content on the module uninstalling confirmation page ?

Comment: What's the error? What kind of content are you talking about?

Comment: [Themes can declare dependencies on modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2937955). Maybe just declare a dependency in your theme?!

Comment: @sonfd i have edited my question, hoping that is clearer